# Package PACKAGE_NAME does not exist

Tags: java, import, package

I want to create a custom package for utility java classes. I want to access those classes from anywhere at anytime. My package source class path is:

> E:/ClassLibrary/lib/util/math/Number.class

My java source code is located at:

> E:/ClassLibrary/src/util/math/Number.java

I have added this path to the windows environment variables:

For system variables:

> CLASS_LIBRARY=E:\ClassLibrary

For environment path:

> %CLASS_LIBRARY%\lib\

This is my code for the Number.java:

```
package util.math;
public class Number {
public static double round(double num) {
    num *= 100;
    num += 0.5;
    num = (int) num;
    num /= 100;
    return num;
}
}
```

And this is the class from where i am trying to import this class;

```
import util.math.*;
public class Package {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String line = Return.object.name("String");
            System.out.println(line);
            Number.round(2.576);
    }
}
```

This class is located at:

> E:/Experiments/Package.java

Whenever I try to compile Package.java.
It says:

```
Package.java:1: error: package util.math does not exist
import util.math.*;
^
Package.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            Number.round(2.576);
                  ^
symbol:   method round(double)
location: class Number
2 errors
```

I have tried every thing.
But none of them works!
I am new to java programming language. 
I am using windows 10, vs-code,
jdk-12

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler output is giving you two specific errors.

The first:

```
Package.java:1: error: package util.math does not exist
import util.math.*;
^
```

There is indeed no such default package available. You might revisit whatever led you to add that line in the first place.

The second:

```
Package.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            Number.round(2.576);
                  ^
symbol:   method round(double)
```

You are asking to call a method `round()` on the `Number` class, but it is telling you it can't find a "round()" thing to run. If you look at Javadoc for `Number` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), you can see a list of methods that are available – none of them are "round()". Again, worth revisiting why you're trying to do `Number.round()`.

In your `Package.java`, you need to edit your code to specify which `Number` class to use, so instead of this:

```
Number.round(2.576);
```

do this:

```
util.math.Number.round(2.576);
```

When compiling `Package.java`, since it is in a different directory from `util/math/Number.java`, you need to tell the compiler where to look for your Number.java, something like this:

```
javac -cp E:/ClassLibrary/src/ Package.java
```

Comment: I am trying to access the `round()` method which is located in the `Number` class I created in the `package **util.math**` and not from the default `Java's Number` class. Its not just about the `round()` method i want to use several other methods as well. I just don't understand that why the package **util.math** which contains the `Number` class is not imported properly even if the environment variables are set, the package is located at correct location as well as the import statement is also correct.

Comment: please any solution! @kaan

Comment: I added a few more details to my post above. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to use the above mentioned command and here is what I got:`E:\Experiments>java Package
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: util/mathematical/Numeric
        at Package.main(Package.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.mathematical.Numeric
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more` @kaan

Comment: I also wanted to ask that since I have added the `Class Library's` path to windows environment variables and still I need to tell the compiler to where to look for `util.math` package everytime? @kaan

Comment: Also I tried to rename to package and class name from `util.math.Number` to `util.mathemtical.Numeric` to avoid confusion but still i tdoes not work! @kaan